# How to close batch file if one line writes multiple lines?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

I have one batch file containing:

```
cmd /k "cd C:\Files\ && for /r %%F in (*) do if %%~zF=0 del %%F"
```

which will delete empty files in a dir but it will check all files so instead of taking up one line of command it will take up n number of commands where n = number of files in C:\Files\ which makes me unable to exit (close) the CMD using the exit command in the next line since it will execute after only 1 command.

How can I close the command after that command is run in this case? Thank you!

Comment: use `cmd /c` instead of `cmd /k`. For the differences see `cmd ?`

Comment: Wow again Stephan to the rescue! Thanks mate :)

Comment: Of course, @Stephan meant to say `cmd /?` instead of `cmd ?` (for those unaware and possibly puzzled by now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I repeat the correct answer given by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) in an answer instead of a comment to avoid a listing of this question as an unanswered question.

Help of command `cmd` displayed by running `cmd /?` explains the difference between usage of option `/C` (close) and option `/K` (keep open).

Well, it is not necessary to use command `cmd` at all inside a batch file as a *.bat file is interpreted by command `cmd`. Therefore the batch file should contain only

```
cd C:\Files\ && for /r %%F in (*) do if %%~zF==0 del "%%F"
```

to delete recursively all files with a file size equal 0 bytes, i.e. empty files.